# How to add close and minimize button to processing program

Tags: arduino, processing

I made a program with processing and arduino to control RGB led using processing 
then I made application .exe from my processing code 
the problem is the application work without close and minimize button .
how can i add it for my application ?

[image: there is the image of my application]

Comment: Please post a [mcve] that we can run ourselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

be sure that you Uncheck the Presentation Mode

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the "Presentation Mode" checkbox is unchecked:

[image: export options window]

If this is checked, your sketch is displayed in full screen. If it's unchecked, your sketch is displayed in a window.